how to generate correct output using 2 yield statements in coroutine?
i have var DICTIONARY, which is a dictionary where the keys are English letters and the values are words that start with the corresponding letter. The initial filling of DICTIONARY looks like this:
DICTIONARY = {
    'a': 'apple',
    'b': 'banana',
    'c': 'cat',
    'd': 'dog',
    ...
}

i'm trying to write coroutine called alphabet, which takes letters as input and returns the words associated with the given letter from the DICTIONARY.
Sample Input 1:

coro = alphabet()
next(coro)
print(coro.send('a'))
print(coro.send('b'))
print(coro.send('c'))

Sample Output 1:
text
apple
banana
cat

Sample Input 2:
python
coro = alphabet()
next(coro)
for letter in 'qwerty':
    print(coro.send(letter))

Sample Output 2:
text
quail
walrus
elephant
rabbit
tiger
yak

my code uses 2 yields , 1 is assigned as variable:
def alphabet():
    while True:
         ch = yield
         yield DICTIONARY[ch]

however 2 yield statements used in coroutine actually skip 1 value always:
Test input:
coro = alphabet()
next(coro)
print(coro.send('a'))
print(coro.send('b'))
print(coro.send('c'))
Correct output:
apple
banana
cat

Your code output:
apple
None #this is the problem
cat

i dont know how to deal with None and it skips 'b' for banana.
updated:
#still dont really get it how it works
def alphabet(letter='a'):
    while True:

        letter = yield DICTIONARY[letter]
  
    


Do you realize that a) next(gen) is equivalent to gen.send(None) and b) yield and yield <something> both consume object fed to .send()? Your problem asks you to 1) load the first character (ch = yield) once, and then 2) yield the word, receiving the next character, and repeat.

And, just for the sake of completeness, please stop calling generators coroutines - these are very related, but different concepts. "coroutine" in python has a well-defined meaning in async world.

@STerliakov, i have updated my question, but still kinda dont get it. i understand i need only 1 yield statement

Oh, cool, now you're somewhat closer, but there's no promise that "a" will be the first letter. Try to add print statements before and after every yield. (and you need two yield statements, not only one)

@STerliakov, i managed to solve it with one. i will add the answer here

Solutions should be posted below with "Your Answer", not in the question.
